# Browser Version and laravel Version

Tags: laravel

Is there any concept like Laravel version vs browser version.
For example, Laravel 5.6 is compatible with Firefox 59.0.2 or not.
Any feedback will be appreciated.

Comment: Why should the framework version in any way relate to the browser? Laravel is a server-side technology.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel is written in PHP. And PHP is a server-side language. Laravel doesn't get executed in the browser.

They do have a set of default css/javascript packages that are used. You can look them up and take a look at their browser support.

Laravel tends to only choose packages that are stable and have a huge browser support.